# Synchronous rectification problems

Tags: rectifier, resonance, synchronous, llc-converter

I am currently designing a LLC resonant converter and am trying to perform synchronous rectification but am running into some issues with it.

[image: LLC Design]

This is my design and note I am currently using the IRFZ48SPBF MOSFET and the FAN3111ESX MOSFET driver as the desired ones were out of stock.

Here is the waveforms I am getting (drain current in green, gate voltage in yellow, drain voltage in blue, and other mosfet gate voltage in purple).

[image: top mosfet gate voltage and drain voltage]
[image: top mosfet and bottom mosfet gate voltage and drain current]

I was pretty sure that this was happening because the secondary was resonating with the parasitic capacitance(s) from the mosfet but the ringing is happening at 2.7 MHz and when I measured all the capacitance values of the MOSFET (Cds = 6.3 nF, Cdg = 3.5 nF, Cgs = 3.7 nF, Lcentretap = 3.9 uH, Lsecondary = 7.5 uH), the largest resonant frequency I could get was 1.4 MHz; This confused me a little bit.

I replaced the mosfets with schottky diodes and the ringing went away (at least the large ringing), so this reinforces my theory, but I am wondering if just replacing the mosfets would work or maybe the drivers have something to do with it too?

Edit: I am concerned because the diodes are much more efficient than the MOSFETs which shouldn’t be the case; the MOSFETs heat up very fast and I think this is happening because they dont fully close causing shoot through... maybe. Oh and the dead time is around 200 ns if that helps.

Comment: What is primary series or leakage inductance? What is sec-sec leakage?

Comment: primary leakage is 27uH not sure what the secondary leakage is

Comment: If you are actually using IRFZ48 MOSFETs, they are just barely specified for 5V gate drive, so they will act as current limiters at about 12 amps. So that may explain why Schottky diodes work better.

Comment: I don't think that is true the data sheet says +-20V

Comment: That is the absolute maximum gate voltage. The characteristic graph shows a minimum drive of 4.5 volts, at which it shows a linear Vds/Id of 0.047 ohms up to 15 amps. Then above 1 volt it levels off at about 18 amps. The Schottky diode will do better if the load needs to draw more than that. If you have the full 5 volts, the current limits at about 30 amps.

Comment: Also, the ON state output voltage of the FAN3111 seems to be about 1 volt below Vcc, so it might be trying to drive the MOSFETs with 4 volts.

Answer (score 3):

Mosfets that run as switches, as long as they are otherwise correctly selected for the application, heat up due to two common reasons:

1. Shoot-through.
2. Linear operation.

In your case, the culprit most likely is #2. As a quick check: double the gate voltage. If the mosfets don't heat anymore, then insufficient gate drive was the problem. That's at least how it works for me 90% of the time.

Comment: The gate voltage is 8 volts. The square waves in the photo are the gates of the mosfets.

Answer (score 2):

> *Cds = 6.3nF, Cdg = 3.5nF, Cgs = 3.7nF*

The [MOSFET data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr3636pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566d1e122698) clearly states that the output capacitance is 332 pF but, for a better figure to use, the *effective output capacitance (time related)* will be more representative (633 pF): -

[image]

If we used this figure and the 3.9 μH we get a resonance of 3.20 MHz and this might easily be as low as 2.7 MHz given that I have used typical figures. For instance if your device was more like 900 pF for the effective time related value then you would get 2.7 MHz.

> *I am wondering if just replacing the mosfets would work or maybe the
> drivers have something to do with it too*

You will get some ringing with this type of design and what I see in your waveforms does not concern me. However, if you see an improvement in power delivery efficiency when replacing the MOSFETs with diodes, then that would concern me.

Comment: hmm that makes sense, I used an lcr meter to measure the capacitances as I thought it would be more accurate, but I guess not. In regards to the efficiency yes the diodes are MUCH more efficient. The mosfets heat up considerably really fast and I think its because they dont fully close and shoot through happens.

Comment: Structurally your schematic doesn't have any obvious failings but the devil can be in the detail and the layout. Your PWM3 and enable signals appear to be fine and have an anti-shoot-through gap.